# Vertical Heading ion left CSS Issue

Tags: html, css

I have to create 2 vertical headings on either side of a box. I have successfully created on right which is working fine with dynamic content.
Problem is coming for left side. Unlike on right heading, when we change content on left side, it moves sideways. Also, it is not moving to extreme left when I add `left: 0rem` code to it.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/77176/)

```css
.section {
  padding: 4.5rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.section .section-heading-vertical {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4rem;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
  padding-right: 9.375rem;
  -moz-transform-origin: right top 0;
  -o-transform-origin: right top 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: right top 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0;
  transform-origin: right top 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg)
}

.section .section-heading-vertical:before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 8rem;
  -moz-transform-origin: right top 0;
  -o-transform-origin: right top 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: right top 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0;
  transform-origin: right top 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg)
}

.section-heading-vertical.on-left {
  left: 4rem;
  right: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <h3 class="section-heading-vertical on-left">Left Header</h3>
  <h3 class="section-heading-vertical">Right Header</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: its seems like the css still uses the original orientation of the element.

Comment: `transform-origin` property is causing the issue. try updating like `transform-origin: left 0%;` for `.section-heading-vertical.on-left` and adjust the top value

Comment: instead of so much css, you should have used `text-orientation` attribute.

Comment: Thank you. didn't know about that attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes using `writing-mode: tb-rl;` and `display: flex;`. Try the snippet below. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.section .section-heading-vertical {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
}

.section .section-heading-vertical:after {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.section-heading-vertical.on-left {
  left: 0rem;
}

.section-heading-vertical.on-right {
  right: 0rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <h3 class="section-heading-vertical on-left">Left Header</h3>
  <h3 class="section-heading-vertical on-right">Right Header</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)